# Possible to have different collateral for each party?

Tags: derivatives, valuation, margin, collateral

Normally bilateral credit support annexes would have both parties post/receive the same collateral be it US treasuries or cash etc. Are there CSAs
Where each party has a different set of eligible collateral? IE party A can post USD cash and treasuries but party B can post EUR cash and Bunds? From a valuation perspective it would be a headache but does this arrangement exist? Would it be possible to have such an agreement?

Comment: That is possible with triparty, both parties may have a different schedule with the triparty agent.

Comment: You could say this is one of the advantages of an Exchange (compared to OTC). I put up the collateral I want at the Exchange, the counterparty puts up the collateral he wants, and we don't even know what each others collateral is, just that it satisfies the requirements of the Exchange.